# CSS animation to occur on a timer to create a heartbeat animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The snippet below shows a spinning circle. Every 1 second I want this circle to double in size and then shrink back to it's original size(to look like a heartbeat). The way I am attempting to do this is by creating a timer in javascript so that every one second, the class which causes the grow effect is removed from the circle, and then immediately added back on. I was hoping that having the class added back on after being removed would trigger the animation but I guess not. Right now the "heartbeat" only happens once.

Also I would like to have the circle spinning at constant speed if that's possible. Right now the circle really slows down at the end, and starts a little bit slow.

```js
// set timeout
let tid = setTimeout(mycode, 1000);
function mycode() {
  // do some stuff...
  let ic = document.getElementById('inner-circle')
  ic.classList.remove('heartbeat')
  ic.classList.add('heartbeat')
  tid = setTimeout(mycode, 1000); // repeat myself
}
function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
  clearTimeout(tid);
}
```

```css
#spinning-circle {
    animation-name: spinning-circle;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.heartbeat {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation-name: heartbeat;
    animation-duration: 0.15s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

#inner-circle img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
    100% {
        transform: scale(2,2);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle">
    <div id='inner-circle'>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNlQ.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript at all:

```css
#spinning-circle {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    animation: spinning-circle linear 10s infinite;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
}

#inner-circle {
    animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;
}

#inner-circle img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    25% {
        transform: scale(2);
    }
    
    50% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0turn);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-1turn);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="spinning-circle">
    <div id='inner-circle'>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNlQ.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It kinda looks like it grows faster than it shrinks though, I was kind of hoping for equal time for both transitions

Comment: @Sam Well, that's how heartbeat actually looks like. If you want them to be evenly timed, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, and remove the `setTimeout()` inside the function `mycode()`

```js
// set timeout
let tid = setInterval(mycode, 1000);
function mycode() {
  // do some stuff...
  let ic = document.getElementById('inner-circle')
  ic.classList.remove('heartbeat')
  ic.classList.add('heartbeat')
}
function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
  clearInterval(tid);
}
```

and for the animation speed add `animation-timing-function: linear;` to `.heartbeat {} and #spinning-circle {}`